# Firebase swift error Storage.storage() cannot find 'Storage' in scope

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

Hi when trying to upload an image to firebase storage I am using the firebase documentation however I am getting this error.

cannot find 'Storage' in scope

```
 let storage = Storage.storage()
 let storageReference = storage.reference()
```

Comment: This question was caused by lack of just `import FirebaseStorage` in the official docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/start#swift

Answer (score 12):

Add next line to your pod file

pod 'Firebase/Storage'

then "pod install" and finally add

import FirebaseStorage

Comment: what about swift package manager